Firebase Emulator Error, Emulator exits because of PubSub
I have been getting this error When I try to start my firebase emulator, so far I have tried the followings:

tried reinstalled node and using lower versions as far as they go all the way to v12
Java sdk reinstallation
firebase cli tools reinstallation

but the error persists.
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
!  pubsub: Fatal error occurred: 
   Pub/Sub Emulator has exited with code: 1, 
   stopping all running emulators
i  pubsub: Stopping Pub/Sub Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub 

this is the error log output.

If you think there's a bug with the emulator that's not related to any code you've written, you should file an issue on GitHub.  Otherwise, your question needs to contain enough details that anyone can use to reproduce what you've done to get to this point.  We need to see what you might have done wrong.
